# Create a column containing list of products that each customer has using groupby in pandas on customer id column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame as shown below

## df

```
cust_id         product
1               tv
1               phone
2               bat
2               ball
3               bat
4               ball
4               bat
4               tv
4               phone
5               tv
6               bat
7               bat
7               ball
7               tv
8               phone
8               tv
```

from the above I would like to prepare below data frame as shown below. Where `product_list` column consist of list of products the elements in the list should be sorted in acsending order.

## Expected output:

```
cust_id           product_list
1                 ['phone', 'tv']
2                 ['ball', 'bat']
3                 ['bat']
4                 ['ball', 'bat', 'phone', 'tv']
5                 ['tv']
6                 ['bat']
7                 ['ball', 'bat', 'phone', 'tv']       
8                 ['phone', 'tv']
```

I tried below code

```
df1 = df.groupby('cust_id').agg(product_list=('product','unique')).reset_index()
df1

    cust_id   product_list
0   1         [tv, phone]
1   2         [bat, ball]
2   3         [bat]
3   4         [ball, bat, tv, phone]
4   5         [tv]
5   6         [bat]
6   7         [bat, ball, tv]
7   8         [phone, tv]
```

But which is not exactly what I want.

I tried below code as well

```
s = df.groupby('cust_id')['product'].apply(list).reset_index()
s.rename({'product':'product_list'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
s
```

what I got is as shown below

```
cust_id product_list
0   1   [tv, phone]
1   2   [bat, ball]
2   3   [bat]
3   4   [ball, bat, tv, phone]
4   5   [tv]
5   6   [bat]
6   7   [bat, ball, tv]
7   8   [phone, tv]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need the values in quotes. here is one way to do it

```
df.groupby('cust_id')['product'].apply(lambda x: [', '.join("'" + item + "'" for item in sorted(x))]).reset_index()
```

```
    cust_id     product
0         1     ['phone', 'tv']
1         2     ['ball', 'bat']
2         3     ['bat']
3         4     ['ball', 'bat', 'phone', 'tv']
4         5     ['tv']
5         6     ['bat']
6         7     ['ball', 'bat', 'tv']
7         8     ['phone', 'tv']
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the data before aggregation:

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'product'])
         .groupby('cust_id')['product'].agg(list)
         .reset_index(name='product_list')
      )
```

Output:

```
   cust_id            product_list
0        1             [phone, tv]
1        2             [ball, bat]
2        3                   [bat]
3        4  [ball, bat, phone, tv]
4        5                    [tv]
5        6                   [bat]
6        7         [ball, bat, tv]
7        8             [phone, tv]
```

Comment: I would like to have the values in quotes